# J8583 - Nested LLLLVAR

Tags: kotlin, variable-length, iso8583, j8583

Is it possible to do nested LLLLVAR using J8583? With the given sample value below the DE 63 which has length of 18 will have its LLLLVAR = `0018313830303030313431313831343030303234`, then using this value we need to get the LLLLVAR again that should end up like this `00200018313830303030313431313831343030303234`. I tried Composite but instead got this `002030303138313830303030313431313831343030303234`

```
val msgFactory = MessageFactory<IsoMessage>()


val isoRequest: IsoMessage = msgFactory.newMessage(0x800)


isoRequest
    .setValue(63, "18" + "0000141181400024", IsoType.LLLLVAR, 999)

log(isoRequest.writeData().bytesToHex())
```

I tried using CompositeField but no luck.

```
val de63 = CompositeField()
de63.addValue(IsoValue(IsoType.LLLLVAR, "18" + "0000141181400024", 999))


isoRequest.setValue(63, de63, de63, IsoType.LLLLVAR, 999)
```

It converted the length of the first LLLLVAR into HEX.

```
002230303138313830303030313431313831343030303234
```

The idea is DE 63 can have multple table ID, here we have '18'

Comment: Does this answer your question? [J8583 set Subfields to IsoMessage object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76383617/j8583-set-subfields-to-isomessage-object)

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz I actually tried that but never managed to successfully get the result I want, the LLLLVAR makes everything turn in hex. I updated the question

Comment: You need to improve on explaining what you tried, it's hard to tell from your words when you say you tried composite. Perhaps showing what you tried in code, and comparing each output with expected.

Next to each code you tried.

Comment: @AndrésAlcarraz, I updated the question with another sample

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally found a proper solution. All we had to do is use LLLLVAR together with LLLLBIN, since doing nested LLLLVAR will convert the length of first LLLLVARed length to ASCII HEX which is incorrect from our requirements.

```
val msgFactory = MessageFactory<IsoMessage>()

val de63Value = "18" + "0000141181400024"
val de63 = CompositeField()
de63.addValue(IsoValue(IsoType.LLLLVAR, de63Value, de63Value.length))

val isoRequest: IsoMessage = msgFactory.newMessage(0x800)
isoRequest.setValue(63, de63, de63, IsoType.LLLLBIN, 999)

log(isoRequest.writeData().bytesToHex())
```